# How to create separate objects using Modular JavaScript pattern

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, canvas

I'm trying to update the interval value x but not succeeding. I hope to eventually have different pawn objects with internal values I can update when keypress up/down/left/right to redraw the canvas.

**Code Update:** Able to update x, y values now, but not sure about creating seperate objects using modular JavaScript pattern.

JavaScript using jQuery 1.5.1:

```
//Constructors
    var pawn = (function() {        

        var x = 25;
        var y = 25;     
        var getX = function() {
            return x;
        };
        var getY = function() {
            return y;
        };

        function _drawPawn(x,y) {
            var x = x || 25;
            var y = y || 25;
            var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
            if (canvas.getContext) {
                var b = $('body');
                var winH = b.height();
                var winW = b.width();
                $(canvas).attr('height',winH).attr('width',winW);
                var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");  
                ctx.beginPath();
                ctx.lineWidth="3";
                ctx.arc(x, y, 10, 0, Math.PI * 2, true); // circle              
                ctx.stroke();
            }
        }

        function left() {
            x = 100;
            y = 100;
        }

        return {
            getX:getX,
            getY:getY,
            draw: function drawPawn(x,y) {
                _drawPawn(x,y);
            },
            left:left
        }
    })();   

    //Init
    $(function() {      
        var b = pawn;
        b.left();
        alert(b.getX());

            var a = pawn;
    alert(a.getX());

        //b.draw();
    });
```

and the html:

```
<canvas id="canvas" height="800px" width="600px">
    Download a modern browser like Internet Explorer 9, Firefox, Safari or Chome to view this.
</canvas>
```

Comment: Pls read comments below Alnitak's answer before answering.

Comment: Answer posted by Alnitak here: http://jsfiddle.net/raybellis/WwV3G/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As it is currently written, your `getX()` function will be automatically invoked with the supplied (empty) parameter list, and return `x`, which is then equivalent to:

```
var getX = x;
```

which will give `getX` the value of `x` *at the time it was declared*.

To fix, removed the parentheses:

```
var getX = function() {
        return x;
};
```

---

You also need to fix this function in your returned object:

```
draw: function drawPawn(x, y) {
    _drawPawn(x, y);
}
```

Since the apparent intent is to call `draw` *without* parameters and use the currently bound `x` and `y` values, it should be:

```
draw: function drawPawn() {
    _drawPawn(x, y);
}
```

Comment: tested, doesn't work. and the way I declared var b = pawn is correct using this pattern?

Comment: return the function as a string it seems

Comment: yes, because you haven't _called_ the function in `b.getX`, you've only obtained a reference to it.  See http://jsfiddle.net/hqxy2/

Comment: BTW, your module pattern probably isn't right - you can only create one 'pawn' - indeed it's the one called `pawn`, and `b` is just another reference to the same object.  I'm not sufficiently expert on JS to fix that, though.

Comment: FWIW, I _think_ you're using the right syntax to _create_ a module, but the 'pawn' should itself be part of that module, not the whole module.

Comment: Ohh... so you've got half the answer.

Comment: Maybe I can't use modules to create separate objects.. but have to use a constructor in the module or apart from the module? I'll wait for anyone who knows this for sure.

Comment: something like that - create a 'chess' module, and have _that_ contain 'pawn: function() { ... }'.  I suggest you ask a new question, though, as this is really a separate problem from the one you were initially trying to solve.

Comment: The initial problem/title still remains: How to create separate objects using Modular JavaScript pattern.

Comment: ah, yes, that was the original point, wasn't it :)  It was obscured by the other bugs in the code.

Comment: I understand why it doesn't work now, with your example. many thanks!

Comment: You're welcome.  TBH I'm still trying to get to grips with JS patterns and in particular how to achieve inheritance myself.

Comment: I'm a fan of the modular method, just needed it to produce the constructors I needed. your fiddler example will be a really good example/cornerstone moving forward, you totally re-arranged the code as it should be re-arranged.

Answer (score -1):

First like alnitak said remove paranthese from getX, getY.
If u want different pawn objects you should use `var b = new pawn()`

Comment: I don't think you can new a module, but you can new constructors. If unsure what I mean by module pattern, read this: http://www.addyosmani.com/resources/essentialjsdesignpatterns/book/

Comment: i don't understandt what u mean, i thought u wanted different pawn objects; if u want just one u can use just the `b = pawn` assignment. And for draw u can use: `draw: _drawPawn(x,y)`

Comment: maybe u should just give it a try.

Comment: what do you mean? i don't understant bc u don't explain what you want to do clearly enough.What are "separate objects?"